# Dynamic Argument in a formula for google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I change the number value in a formula such as the one below:

=LOOKUP(1, ARRAYFORMULA(1/('Sheet1'!11:11<>"")),'Sheet1'!11:11)

This formula searches a given row (in this case row 11 on Sheet1) and outputs the last entered value.

Ideally I would like to vary the given row based on an row I input without having to retype the formula.

I've tried using direct cell references in place of the numbers (such *'Sheet1'!C1:C1* where C1 contains the row I want to output) for the last argument of LOOKUP but that didn't work.

I've also tried replacing the whole reference with a cell reference that has a dynamic value such as below:

=LOOKUP(1, ARRAYFORMULA(1/('C1<>"")),C1)

where C1 contains the concatenate formula to build the text "'Sheet1'!X:X" and X is a specified number.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the last non-empty value in row 11, use:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(11:11,1),-1)
```

If the row range is entered in another cell, for example `A1`, use INDIRECT:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(INDIRECT(A1),1),-1)
```